# how to describe to a jew what tefillin is?

Tags: tefilin, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

BH i very often have the merit of putting tefillin on jews that have never put it on. how do i describe to them what it does spiritually?

Comment: What makes you think there is anything more to it than fulfilling the command of God?

Answer (score 12):

For the uninitiated I would start with Rav Yosef Karo's explanation for the placement of *t'filin*: One goes next to the brain to represent one's intellectual recognition and obedience of God and one goes next to the heart to represent one's emotional recognition and obedience of God. ([Source](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%94) - *Orach Chayim* 25:5)

Answer (score 7):

You should also tell them what it does for you, **personally**, when *you* put them on.

Chances are, you don't know what that is.  After you pay enough attention to be able to explain to someone else what it does for **you** to put them on, you will probably find you are **much** more successful at getting others to do so.